# the timsort algorithm implemented in python sorted() method

Tags: php, python, sorting, timsort

I want to know if there is any algorithm in PHP which would be the equivalent algorithm of the timsort algorithm implemented in Python for sorting lists ?

It so happened that I had to translate some code from python to php.

Comment: Is there a need to use Timsort to sort the data? You can't just use any old sort function? I don't know what's default in php (probably quicksort or merge sort) but I'm sure it's a decent enough algorithm.

Comment: The method of sorting is an implementation detail that you shouldn't have to worry about.  (Hmm...  just googled and found that PHP's sort may not be stable -- you'll have to decide if that matters.)

Comment: Should we read your question as "is there any php implementation of timsort?"?.
Anyway you may try to understand the algorithm looking [here](http://www.drmaciver.com/2010/01/understanding-timsort-1adaptive-mergesort/) and [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt). This last link being the python source file of the list-sorting algorithm(which has an explanation of it).

Answer (score 0):

According to wiki python's sort() is a timsort

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

you could always try to write your own implementation of timsort in php. I suggest reading up on timsort and looking at a few examples.

https://github.com/swenson/sort